Conjecture on Infinitely Many Consecutive Pairs of Early Primes
An early prime is one which is less than the arithmetic mean of the prime before and the prime after.
Conjecture: There are infinitely many consecutive pairs of early primes

MY attempt
Well, the fact that infinitely often $g_n<g_{n+1}$ is trivial, because we know that prime gaps can become arbitrarily large (we don't need bounded gaps and we don't even need to know the PNT for this, just consider $n!+2,n!+3,\dots,n!+n$).
But this only proves the existence of infinitely many early primes, whereas the conjecture asks for infinitely many consecutive pairs of early primes, which would correspond to $g_n<g_{n+1}<g_{n+2}$ infinitely often.
This would certainly follow immediately if we knew the Hardy-Littlewood prime $k$-tuple conjecture (the natural generalization of the twin prime conjecture), so we should certainly believe it to be true
but there might also be a more elementary proof for this....?

As you are aware, these sort of conjectures are easy to make but tend to be beyond the reach of current understanding. Any reason to imagine this one is different?  Can you, say, calculate a heuristic density for such pairs and compare that to a deep search?

Could you explain a little more - for example, what is $g_n$? Versions of the tuple conjecture have been proven, which may be strong enough (see eg https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/polymath8b-bounded-intervals-with-many-primes-after-maynard/ )

The sequence of weak primes https://oeis.org/A051635 (they call these "weak primes" but mention that Erdos called them "early primes") - the existence of infinitely many such pairs is a conjecture of Erdos.  It seems like a very reasonable conjecture - I would imagine $g_n < g_{n+1} < g_{n+2}$ happens about one-sixth of the time.

@MarkBennet To clarify, $g_n$ represents the $n$-th prime gap, thanks a lot for nice link

Although this statement seems to be quite weak , I guess it has no known proof.

@Peter Posting this question on MO might help??

I do not think so because you already mentioned correctly that the conjecture is almost surely true. All we need is Schinzel's hypothesis. On the other hand , I doubt that this conjecture has been proven. Taos result does not help because 1. The gaps are equal and 2. (even worse) it has not been proven that there are arbitary long arithmetic progressions consisting of CONSECUTIVE prime numbers.
